# Angularjs: how to pass entire object to another controller?

Tags: angularjs

OK, I'm very new to AngularJS.  I'm converting a rather rough-app (that I've been writing for a couple of days) from using mostly jQuery over to using Angular.  [ I discovered Angular "mid-stream", while researching how to alleviate all the bookmark and back-button headaches I was running into.]

On my main page, I have a table of search results. (If the user arrives without passing any parameters, a default search is called to build the table.  And, of course, they can use a search form on that page to show themselves a different set of results.)

Now, when the user clicks on a table item, I want that table to more or less "become" a drop-down menu on the Item Details page that can be used to navigate from one table item to the next. (The list will usually be less than 20 items long at any given time.) Same data, same sort order, just in a different control.

Rather than build that "Child" page so that (in addition to making Ajax calls to pull up the item details) it runs the exact same query AGAIN and then builds a drop-down out of it... I thought perhaps there was some more-efficient way to do it.

Perhaps, pass the entire object of objects from the search results on to the Details controller?  (I would somehow have to also pass an id for whichever item the user actually clicked on for details as well.)

[With jQuery, I had been building both the drop-down and the table of results on the same page...and then just use show() and hide() to alternate which one I was displaying.  And I would fetch the Item Details data and populate/show hidden details divs whenever a table row or drop-down option was selected.]

Comment: From the guidelines: Don't ask about...
Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I think you should use some kind of routing, maybe this can be helpful

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

And second one, if you want to access same object with multiple controllers, you should use factory with your object, and all you need is to inject that factory into your controllers, and you will have access to the same object from multiple controllers. Here is the short tutorial, it's very easy to understand:

https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-sharing-data-between-controllers

And third option, but it's not nice, is to emit or broadcast event and send object from one controller, and in another one you can put a listener for that event, here you can find more information:

http://www.theroks.com/angularjs-communication-controllers/

http://toddmotto.com/all-about-angulars-emit-broadcast-on-publish-subscribing/

Comment: For those who may follow:    I found the video at this link very helpful --->   http://onehungrymind.com/building-a-website-with-angularjs-pt-2-now-with-state/

Using that, I was able to simply take my object of found search results, store it within the service, then pull it out again in a different view on a different controller.